# Hierarchical configuration file in perl

Tags: xml, json, perl, configuration-files, perl-hash

I am writing a test automation software in perl and I came across a problem with the configuration files I defined. 
The automation software receives an input CFG file written in perl hash that among other things defines the images to build. 
Now the same images needs to be built in different test scenarios, e.g. nightly build, hourly build and weekend regression. 
Currently we have to define the same images in 3 different files and any time we want to update them (say update the git branch) we need to do it in 3 files.
I am looking for a solution where i can create one file that defines the builds and let the other files inherit from it. 
I am looking for a built in language feature in perl/xml/json/etc. not something i need to implement myself inside the test software.

for example

night cfg file:

```
builds => {
        smp_be => {
                  name => image_smp
                  branch => 2011.12
                  compiler => little_endian
         }
        up_be => {
                  name => image_up
                  branch => 2011.12
                  compiler => big_endian
         }

}
some other ** night **  specific stuff...
```

weekend cfg file

```
builds => {
            smp_be => {
                      name => image_smp
                      branch => 2011.12
                      compiler => little_endian
             }
            up_be => {
                      name => image_up
                      branch => 2011.12
                      compiler => big_endian
             }

    }
    some other ** weekend ** specific stuff...
```

instead i would like to have something like

night cfg file

```
builds {
     # im inventing this syntax up
     # common_builds.cfg contains the previous files
     include common_builds.cfg
 }
some other ** night **  specific stuff...
```

Please advise

thanks in advance

Comment: After searching some more i believe i found an option to do this using xml. there are 2 different features in xml supporting this: external entity and xinlcude. ill try this out and update if it does the job

Answer (score 0):

Provided the top-level keys are different, you could simply merge the hashes in Perl:

```
my $builds_hashref = loaded_from_build_file();
my $scenario_hashref = loaded_from_scenario_file();

my $config_hashref = { %$builds_hashref, %$scenario_hashref };
```

. . . of course assuming you have implemented the logic to load generic config from any file.

If the keys are the same at the top level, this merge would become more complicated, but is still possible, provided you know precisely where the config keys between build and scenario files will differ.

Comment: This is good but not generic enough. in my "father" CFG file i want to be able to specify which builds from which file to inherit.

Comment: OK, I think you will get more answers if you add some minimal examples to your question, including build config, scenario config and the expected "output" config that a test should use.